# Get a sequence bits from a unsigned long c

Tags: c, algorithm, if-statement, cryptography, sequence

I am wondering if anyone can help me I am just learning c and I apologize in advance if I am using the incorrect terms. I am trying to implement a an algorithm but I am having a problem at one particular part where there is a check compare a sequence of bits.

The algorithm  states this check.

[image: algorithm if check]

But cant seem to find an example how to implement the if statement part.

```
        unsigned long zprime   = 2501328903
        unsigned long q0XORq1  = 3736417748;

        if ( q0XORq1 == zprime )
        {

        }
```

so I want to compare bits 8 to 23 on q0XORq1 to bits 8 to 23 on zprime

Comment: Does it mean that you don't care about bits 1-7 and 24-rest?

Comment: the bits not listed I don't care about, only the sequence stated I mean in algorithm

Answer (score 3):

You use bit-masking to do so, so basically you define a mask that is setting bits 8-23 to '1' and all the rest as '0' then you use AND (&) operator  on your value and this mask to ignore all other parts, like:

```
unsigned long zprime   = 2501328903
unsigned long q0XORq1  = 3736417748;

if ( (q0XORq1 & 0xFFFF00) == (zprime & 0xFFFF00) )
{

}
```

I would suggest to learn all operators in C, here you got good place to start:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Answer (score -1):

1. Write a function that returns a number in which all but bits 8-23 are turned off.

   ```
   unsigned long getTransformedNumber(unsigned long in);
   ```
2. Use that function while comparing the numbers.

   ```
   if ( getTransformedNumber(q0XORq1) == getTransformedNumber(zprime) )
   {
      ...
   }
   ```

You can implement `getTransformedNumber` as:

```
unsigned long getTransformedNumber(unsigned long in)
{
   unsigned long mask = 0;
   if ( sizeof(in) == 32 )
   {
      mask = 0xFFFF00;
   }
   else if ( sizeof(in) == 64 )
   {
      mask = 0xFFFF0000000000;
   }
   else
   {
      // Make sure to deal with the case where sizeof(in) is
      // different from 32 and 64.
      assert(0);
   }

   return (mask & in);
}
```

**Clarification regarding bits 8-23**

For a 32 bit unsigned long, the bits 8-23 are the middle 16 bits. Hence, the mask `0x00FFFF00` works without any confusion.

However, for a 64 bit unsigned long, the notion of bits 8-23 is not clear. If you use mask `0x0000000000FFFF00`, you pick the bits 8-23 from the right hand side. If you use the mask `0x00FFFF0000000000`, you pick the bits 8-23 from the left hand side. Depending on which bits are desired, you need to pick the right mask.

Comment: @R Sahu Even if sizeof(in) == 64 the mask would still be 0xFFFF00, this 0xFFFF0000000000 will set bit's 40-55.

Comment: @koper89, it depends. If the OP wants the most significant 8-23 bits, then what I suggest is what they need.

Comment: @R Sahu There's only one most significant bit, so saying that someone want's X most significant bits would be semantically incorrect. So I'm pretty sure they didn't mean that.

Comment: @koper89, the most significant 8th bit through the most significant 23rd bit.

Comment: @R Sahu To be fair I would not understand the question, or find it really misleading because for me 8th bit is still 8th bit which is 0x100, if you would say that 8th bit counting from most significant bit to 24th bit counting from most significant bit. But it's just subjective, because it's semantics.

It's a little bit like trying to say that you want value 1 from maximum value. Instead of saying you want maximum value minus 1.